# Disable Geosearch esri controls in leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

It is possible to disable the Geosearch esri controls in leaflet after the first geocode search?.When i run chrome console and i select the search geocode icon this is the code:  `<input class="geocoder-control-input leaflet-bar">`, i have tried to disable using `$('.geocoder-control-input leaflet-bar').attr('disabled', true);` but doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean something,like this: `document.getElementsByClassName("geocoder-control-input")[0].disabled = true;`

Comment: This option works great to disable the geosearch esri controls.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad to help @user19566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your code (which you didn't share) the control is being initialized and added to the map. Like this:

```
var geosearch = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch(...).addTo(map);
```

Or something like this:

```
var geosearch = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch(...);

map.addControl(geosearch);
```

If you don't need the control ever, you can just remove those lines. If you want to be able to add it later you can just remove the `.addTo(map)` or `map.addControl(geosearch)` parts. You can remove it once it added by using the `removeControl` method of `L.Map` In short it works like this:

```
var geosearch = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch(...);

// Add control to the map
map.addControl(geosearch);

// Remove control from the map
map.removeControl(geosearch);
```

References:

- http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/controls/geosearch.html
- http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-addcontrol
- http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removecontrol

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This option removes the controls and works very well.